# Minimum OS version number, iPhone app

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've built an iPhone app which is live in the app-store. When originally submitting the app it showed up in App Store as requiring iPhone OS 3.1.3. When later updating the app I made sure my settings in Xcode for the target for the app store build had the Base SDK version set to 3.1.3 and the Deployment Target version set to 3.0, however it still shows up in app store as requiring 3.1.3.

From what I've understood the Deployment Target version is the one setting the requirement in app store?

Or is there any information concerning this that I should have updated in iTunes Connect when submitting the updated app?

Thanks, Michael

Answer (score 1):

Check the MinimumOSVersion key in your info.plist

Comment: I have a "appName"-Info.plist file in resources, is this the one? If I open it in xcode I can only see 12 keys and values. When pressing a key a dropdown list appears but I can't see a MinimumOSVersion key anywhere. Do I add this myself? I'm totally lost here...

Answer (score 0):

You can set base SDK for your application from edit Project settings
Base SDK